# Is there a way to not use bilingual dictionaries when I try to think in English?

Tags: dictionaries, learning

Is there a way to not use bilingual dictionaries when I try to think in English? For the physical objects of the world (such as a rafter, a scraper, a condenser, etc.) I can use visual dictionaries. But what about abstract ideas (such as 'ambiguous', 'malice', 'deduce', etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to learn English without reference to a bilingual dictionary. Children do it all the time.

Are you able to give 10 hours a day to study with a group of native speakers (at least one who will go everywhere with you) for the next ten years? It is this sort of depth of study that you have when learning your native language that you just don't have the time for when learning a second language.

You can learn new words by hearing or reading them, guessing their meaning, using them (perhaps wrongly) being understood or misunderstood, and constantly developing your understanding of the word. It is a slow process.

You can take some shortcuts by using a monolingual dictionary to learn new words. But the quickest way to grow your vocabulary is to use your native language as a scaffold.

Answer (score 1):

Most learners find it difficult to avoid using bilingual dictionaries, and you shouldn't feel guilty for consulting them.

That said, once you reach a certain level in a language, it's a good discipline to try to understand things by looking them up in a monolingual dictionary.  I would recommend that (at least to start off with) you use dictionaries specifically targeted at learners rather than at native speakers.  Learners are fortunate in that a number of these are available for free online:

- [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/ambiguous) has this entry for "ambiguous" (along with symbols indicating that this word has medium frequency and that it's useful for academic purposes): "something that is ambiguous is unclear, confusing, or not certain, especially because it can be understood in more than one way."
- [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/ambiguous) has this: "1. not clear and therefore capable of being understood in more than one way.  2. confusing or not definite, and therefore difficult to understand."
- [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ambiguous) has: "having or expressing more than one possible meaning, sometimes intentionally".
- M-W [Learner's Dictionary](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/ambiguous) has: "1. able to be understood in more than one way : having more than one possible meaning. 2. not expressed or understood clearly."

You can look up several words in each dictionary and see which one serves you best, or sometimes you may wish to consult multiple dictionaries.

All of them will also give example sentences for most or all words.